# The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

i want to call pager adapter in my view pager so below is my code

```
public class MyFragmentSimilarPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

ArrayList<GetProductDetail.SimilarProductDetailData> list;
LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
public MyFragmentSimilarPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<GetProductDetail.SimilarProductDetailData> list, LinearLayout mLinearLayout ) {
    super(fm);
    this.list=list;
    this.mLinearLayout=mLinearLayout;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment(mLinearLayout);
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    Log.d("PRID AT",list.get(arg0).getId());
    data.putString("prid", list.get(arg0).getSlug());
    myFragment.setArguments(data);
    return myFragment;
}

/** Returns the number of pages */

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return list.size();

}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "Page #" + ( position + 1 );
   }

}
```

Call this adapter form my activity classs

```
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mAdapter = new MyFragmentSimilarPagerAdapter(fm, Tags.mArrayListSimilarProduct,mLinearLayoutBottom);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

when i run this code i get error like **java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged** any idea how can i solve this? your all suggestions are appreciable

Logcat output

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 2, found: 3 Pager id: com.shopping.addtobuy:id/vpPager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class adapter.MyFragmentSimilarPagerAdapter
 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:999)
 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
 at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
```

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: Are you using gridview/listview and onitem click calls the activity with viewpager?

Comment: Smit.Satodia : Yes Recycleview i use

Comment: basilisk: see my logcat output i mention in my question

Comment: Taking a guess here but sharing the linear layout between the fragments seems suspicious. Why do they share it in first place?

Comment: GPuschka  its my view demand because i have to hide layout with some conditions